# How to fill triangle hole of mesh?

Tags: modeling, mesh, materials, modifiers, uv

It would be very appreciated if someone know how can I turn this triangle mesh to proper mesh.

3d file:https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HlKps1PNBrXrzZWu9mEfq2yhZJAADu1H/view

[image]

Comment: I think it might be more trouble fixing than it's worth fixing that instead of just adding a fresh icosphere. But you could try transforming to sphere and then using F to fill in the holes.

Comment: Can you explain a bit?

Comment: Well I mean, unless you just want to fill in the holes and keep the strange topology, just making a new mesh would be a lot easier, as there's really no fast way to do that due to the nature of your mesh.

Comment: You can fill in a hole in your mesh by selecting three to four vertices and pressing F

Comment: Oh! Yeah. But I need exactly this mesh. It's for Pro evolution soccer. I have to convert it to work properly. Thanks I'll try it.